# FCM Notification sending error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to send Notification in both mode with Payload and without it. In earlier it was working fine but after some time it show failed every time when tried to send Notification via Firebase Console.

[image]

I've already done successful setup for Firebase in Android.
I've tried with reinstall app again & again and also tried with different devices, but same problem.

Please suggest me why it is behaving like this.

Comment: check the registration token, may be you can change it

Comment: Your registration token is not registered, kindly check it

Comment: @Akshay Bhat 'AB' i have tried with newest token and also reinstall app again and again but no luck.

Comment: @Nainal i have tried with newest token. have u idea there iis any need to change google-services.json file??

Comment: @Deepak John which keyhash

Comment: @Garg's, sorry meant make sure that  sha1 is correct. Are you using custom payload?

Comment: @Deepak John yes SHA1 is correct in starting i was receiving notifications but later on what happen i don't know but suddenly it show FAILED every time.

Comment: @Garg's connect your device to the system and look whether there is an error while new token is received or when notification is received and check your logcat whether it shows for any error related to token registration